# How to get around net::ERR_FAILED 200

Tags: javascript, html, proxy, html5-canvas, embed

So basically what im doing here is taking an embed, duplicating it to a canvas and then trying to change the background of said duplication transparent. It does work, however not in the browser due to net:ERR_FAILED 200.

Access to image at 'https://clearoutside.com/forecast_image_small/50.70/-3.52/forecast.png' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Any way to get around that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="eng">


<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta nameset="viewport" content="with=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ClearOutside</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: transparent;

            -ms-zoom: 0.5;
            -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
            -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
            -o-transform: scale(0.5);
            -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
            -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body style="background-color:Blue">
    <a href="https://clearoutside.com/forecast/50.70/-3.52">
        <img id="forecast" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://clearoutside.com/forecast_image_small/50.70/-3.52/forecast.png" /></a>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="505" height="41">


        <script>
            document.getElementById("forecast").onload = function(_) {
                const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                const image = document.getElementById("forecast");
                context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

                const WHITE = 0xFF;
                const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                const {
                    data
                } = imageData;
                for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
                    if (
                        WHITE === data[i] &&
                        WHITE === data[i + 1] &&
                        WHITE === data[i + 2]
                    ) {
                        data[i + 3] = 0x00;
                    }
                }
                context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
            };
        </script>


</body>

</html>
```

So perhaps have my own server be responsible for downloading the image, however i have no clue how to set something like that up as im pretty fresh to coding.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set up [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for the API you are consuming

Comment: Hi . Do you solve your problem? I have same issue when calling a rest wcf service by fetch method. my service work fine when running in browser and in postman.