# Not getting data from my API even though the status is 200?

Tags: php, html, laravel, cordova

I have a problem with my API. here's the situation :

- I have API created with laravel
- I want to fetch the data from index.html with jQuery
- I have hosting the API for the server (laravel), in free hosting infinityfree.
- for the index.html it still on my localhost. Because the idea is I'm using Cordova Apache for the view and will converted into apk later.
- when I'm in the localhost an run the laravel server (with PHP artisan serve), it works perfectly fine, but when I hosted it, I cant get the data
- the weird part is that, my status for the request is 200, but I received an error. But when I click the endpoint using dev tool -> browser, the data shows
- [image]

I don't know what the cause of the problem, since in my localhost is just fine. can anyone help me?

EDIT:

- here's the response when I try with postman
  [image]
- again, in localhost, it shows the data, not this

EDIT :

- all my return request is like this :

```
return response()->json([
     'status' => true
], 200);
```

- and the jQuery ajax like this :

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: GLOBAL_URL + "endpointapi",
    dataType: "json",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
success : function(){},
etc...
```

mm.... anyone?

EDIT:
Is hosting service provider matter? I mean since I'm using free hosting, I'm afraid that is limited and can't use for API purpose. If so, anyone know a free hosting and can use for API purpose?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get around net::ERR\_FAILED 200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71108904/how-to-get-around-neterr-failed-200)

Comment: nope, i have setting up the cors from .htacess and in public/index.php but the cors problem still persists

Comment: The screenshot you show as the response in Postman looks like just the HTML source of the page.  So your Laravel app is returning HTML, not a rendered page.  That usually means PHP is not installed or set up on your server.  If you visit the Laravel site in your browser, what do you see?

Comment: I see the usual welcome page, with php installed 8.2 

and if I go to my endpoint API from browser search, the API returns the correct data. I just can't get the data with postman, or ajax. it's really strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok everyone, I think I have the answer. simple... It's because infinity free hosting cannot use for API purposes (for free version, IDK for the paid version). You can search it why it cannot support for API purposes.

I change my hosting to paid hosting (of course not in infinityfree app), and then it works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds to me like you are facing a CORs issue where you are trying to fetch data from your InfinityFree hosted API from your localhost.

**CORS** means Cross-Origin Resource Sharing and for the most part laravel is equipped to properly deal with it. You might just need to configure `config/cors.php` **paths** key.

[Laravel Documentation on CORS](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#cors)

Comment: yes, I faced with cors error, but I've read articel here and there. I have set up the cors in /public.index.php no luck, setting up in /public_html/.htaccess no luck. it still cors block

Comment: but in localhost, i faced cors, but the data successfully return. soI thought maybe the error is not come from cors

Comment: I'm assuming in localhost the request is coming from the same origin where the resource is located unless you have pretty URLs and have resource in `location.test` and making the request from `anotherlocation.test`